# Cannot publish Razor Pages web app to Azure after upgading .NET from 5 to 6

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a Razor Pages project running on Azure web app service on Linux on .NET 5. I have been using zip deployment to publish it without any problems.

Now I want to upgrade to .NET 6, so I have changed the .NET version for the project, updated the NuGet packages from 5 to v6, changed the target version in Azure to 6, changed the target version in the publish profile to v6, but whenever I try to publish it fails every time.

I have followed the required steps as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

If I roll the entityframeworkcore packages back to v5 then it publishes OK. What am I doing wrong?

The publish profile is framework-dependent. The only error message I get on publish is:

> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
>
> ```
> ===================
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.ZipDeploy.targets(55,5): Error : >Zip Deployment failed. 
> 3>Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
> ========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
> ```

Comment: Is it a virtual machine youre uploading to or app service? if its a viertual machine you will have to upgrade the framework, or deploy as self contained instead of framework dependant

Comment: `it fails every time` how is it failing?

Comment: Any error message that you see?

Comment: updated the question to give more info

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same migration of an ASP.NET Core project from .NET 5 to .NET 6 and was able to publish to Azure successfully.

To do that, make sure you are following the correct [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

***Make sure that after adding .NET 6 and update all the packages you have restart the application. Or close or reopen and then try to build again.***

I added the following to my application:

```
Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-convert5to6ajay-F19DC718-9xxx-4xx4-8E14-xxxx</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.3" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.3" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.23.0" />      //add below packages as you have entityframework
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="6.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include=Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0."
 />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

And in `appsettings.json` added the below code:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Aspnetcore": "Warning"
      
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

[image]

Then I restarted the application and then built and published it to Azure:

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer [this blog post](https://haacked.com/archive/2019/07/12/deploy-to-azure/).